# Adding a constant value to zeros in a log normal model and back calculate

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lognormal-distribution

I'm fairly new to GLM and would like some advice on the lognormal model with glm() in R.

I have a bunch of zeros in my data and I realised that there are models out there like the zero-altered Gamma or the Tweedie model are better choice, but I would like to compare them to the lognormal model, i.e. glm (fml, family=gaussian(link="log"))).

The question is, can I add a constant to the DV and use this model? Also, do I just subtract the constant from the model estimates at the end? Is this valid at all?